# Мигание блока при переходе по якорной ссылке

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, animate, background

Есть скрипт, для плавного скроллинга к блоку по определенной ссылке. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после полного завершения прокрутки к этому блоку он мигнул background`ом.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav").on("click","a#anchor", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
     $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500, function () {
  // тут мигнуть background'ом
});
```